# REST principle - resource update

Tags: rest

Can you please confirm if below implementation for PUT vs POST defies REST principle:

---

If a resource was created via POST, allow update to the resource via POST (else return 412 error)
If the resource was created via PUT, allow update to resource via PUT (else return 412 error)

---

I understand both PUT and POST can be used to create a resource. What I think is not right in this case is dependency on how resource was created (PUT/ POST) and takes action based on it. Can you point me to the RFC?

Comment: In general, you can use any of them, but standard is: POST for creating new resource, and PUT for replacing all current representations of the target resource, PATCH for updating some portions of target resource.

Answer (score 2):

---

If a resource was created via POST, allow update to the resource via POST (else return 412 error)
If the resource was created via PUT, allow update to resource via PUT (else return 412 error)

---

> Can you please confirm if below implementation for PUT vs POST defies REST principle

It's probably wrong, but not necessarily so.

In particular, [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) in HTTP has very specific semantics

> The PUT method requests that the state of the target resource be created or replaced with the state defined by the representation enclosed in the request message payload.

In other words, PUT is appropriate for replace, but it is not appropriate for modify.

So what your guideline is actually implying is that if you create a resource via a PUT of its representation, then all subsequent changes to that resource must also be complete replacements.

It's not obvious to me that's a good idea, and there is nothing in HTTP that requires you to be so strict; but it's certainly possible that your guideline authors had some bad experiences, which may be specific to the circumstances in which those guidelines apply.

The notes about using 412 response is... odd.  Again, in HTTP, [412](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-4.2) has a very specific meaning; and that meaning is not related to the method used in the request.  Using a conditional request to ensure that your edit doesn't conflict with another is good idea.

But if somebody has done a POST where they should do a PUT, or vice versa, then the correct status code to return in that case is [405](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.5).

> The 405 (Method Not Allowed) status code indicates that the method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource.  The origin server MUST generate an Allow header field in a 405 response containing a list of the target resource's currently supported methods.
>
> Can you point me to the RFC?

There is no "RFC" for REST; it's not a standard, in that sense.  REST is just a set of architectural constraints discovered by Roy T. Fielding during the early web standardization process.  The appropriate reference is [Chapter 5](http://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) of Fielding's thesis.

HTTP as a standard does (for the most part) use an architecture that satisfies the REST constraints.  As of late 2016, the standard is documented by RFCs [7230-7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-1) inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

A RESTful URL typically points to either a `collection` or an `element`.

A `collection` is typically denoted in plural and could look like this:
    `https://www.example.com/api/v1/cars`

An `element` is typically adressed with its identifier and could look like this:
    `https://www.example.com/api/v1/cars/17`

`Collection`s can be children to `element`s:

```
<code>https://www.example.com/api/v1/workplaces/22/rooms</code>
```

Doing a `POST` to a `collection` usually means creating an `element` in the `collection` and the new `element` is typically returned with the response. The server would be responsible for creating the `URI` for the newly created element. It is the recommended "RESTful" way of creating `element`s.

Doing a `POST` to a `element` is not often used (and discouraged) as that would mean the client would be the one assigning the `identifier`. If used, most often, it means that you treat the `element` as a `collection` in itself and create a new `element` within it.

Doing a `PUT` to a `collection` is perfectly valid "RESTfulness" but would typically mean *replacing* the entire `collection`.

Doing a `PUT` to an `element` is common and typically means replacing the entire `element`, meaning that the entire `element` should be passed along in the request body. Some argue it is fine for the `element` to be created if it does not exist (but I would argue it being a bad request).

Doing a `PATCH` to an `element` typically means updating the `element`. The fields that should be updated are the only fields necessary in the request body.

I've never stumbled on doing a `PATCH` to a `collection` and would probably recommend against it.